# How to detect, if a bezier curve intersects a specified ellipse?

Tags: c#, wpf, geometry

I have a custom control that renders a bezier line from the top-left to the bottom-right corner. I would like to modify the hit test behavior so that the control is only "hit", if hovering over or near the bezier curve, but `FillContainsWithDetail` doesn't return the expected results.

What am I missing?

Here's a derived example class:

```
public class BezierControl : FrameworkElement
{
    protected override HitTestResult HitTestCore(PointHitTestParameters hitTestParameters)
    {
        if (_geometry == null) return null;
        
        var p = hitTestParameters.HitPoint;

        EllipseGeometry expandedHitTestArea = new EllipseGeometry(p, 10.0, 10.0);
        
        var intersection = expandedHitTestArea.FillContainsWithDetail(_geometry);
        if (intersection > IntersectionDetail.Empty)
        {
            return new PointHitTestResult(this, hitTestParameters.HitPoint);
        }

        return null;
    }

    private StreamGeometry _geometry;

    private StreamGeometry getGeometry()
    {
        var result = new StreamGeometry();

         
            using (var context = result.Open())
            {
                var start = new Point(0, 0);
                var startCp = new Point(10, 0);
                var end = new Point(this.ActualWidth, this.ActualHeight);
                var endCp = new Point(this.ActualWidth - 10, this.ActualHeight);

                context.BeginFigure(start, false, false);
                context.BezierTo(startCp, endCp, end, true, false);
            }
     

        result.Freeze();

        return result;
    }
    
    
    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
    {
        base.OnRender(dc);

        if (_geometry == null) _geometry = getGeometry();

        dc.DrawGeometry(null, _pen, _geometry);
    }

    private Pen _pen = new Pen(Brushes.Red, 1.0);

}
```

**EDIT**: The approved answer below is fine, but it also lead me to another alternative - or showed me why my attempted solution was failing: I was creating the geometry like this:

```
context.BeginFigure(bezier.Start, false, false);
```

The first `bool` parameter is called `isFilled`. Setting this to `true` allows intersecting between `_geometry` and `expandedHitTestArea`.

Before noticing this, I implemented the accepted answer below and decided to create the `widenedGeometry` lazily for performance reasons. Which now gets me wondering: from a performance perspective, which approach is better? Or, is this negligible in this case, because geometries are inexpensive anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need that EllipseGeometry. Just check if the hit point is inside a *widened path geometry* of the original geometry (which may of course also be created once when `_geometry` is created):

```
protected override HitTestResult HitTestCore(PointHitTestParameters hitTestParameters)
{
    if (_geometry != null)
    {
        var widenedGeometry = _geometry.GetWidenedPathGeometry(new Pen(null, 20));

        if (widenedGeometry.FillContains(hitTestParameters.HitPoint))
        {
            return new PointHitTestResult(this, hitTestParameters.HitPoint);
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```